# Entity Framework Doesn't Return Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql, frameworks, entity

I am beating my head against the wall. I have reviewed and tried every solution given here on SO, but nothing is working.

It seems simple, yet here I am.

I have a database-first, entity framework model that utilizes stored procedures. The stored procedures are assigned via the EDMX designer. I have a class called Attraction, which has a related table called Configuration. Ideally, what I want to do is create the Attraction object, then the Configuration object, and save them both with one call.

```
Attraction attraction = new Attraction();
Configuration config = new Configuration();

<... assign properties to attraction  ...>
<... assign properties to config ...>

attraction.Configurations.Add(config);

//Now we save
if (!aContainer.AddUpdate(false, attraction))
{
    DisplayNotification(String.Format("An error occurred saving {0}", a.AttractionCode), true);
     return false;
}


<------- MY SERVICE LAYER ------->
    public virtual bool AddUpdate(bool isUpdate, T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isUpdate)
            {
                return (Repository.Update<T>(entity));
            }
            else
            {                   
                return (Repository.Create<T>(entity) != null);
            }
        }
        catch (EntityCommandExecutionException ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException aex)
        {
            Logger.Error(aex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

     <------- MY CREATE METHOD ------->
    public virtual T Create<T>(T tObject) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            var newItem = dbContext.Set<T>().Add(tObject);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            dbContext.Entry<T>(newItem).Reload();
            return newItem;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errors = ex.EntityValidationErrors;
            string msg = string.Empty;

            foreach (DbEntityValidationResult error in errors)
            {
                var errs = error.ValidationErrors;
                foreach (DbValidationError er in errs)
                {
                    msg += er.ErrorMessage + "\n";
                }

            }

            Logger.Error("DbEntityValidationException error creating record: " + msg, ex);
            return null;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("ArgumentException error creating record.", ex);
            return null;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("DbUpdateException error creating record.", ex);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error creating record.", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Nothing I try works. I have tried saving the attraction first, but the primary key never gets returned. It keeps a value of 0, even when I reload the object. In the EDMX designer, I have tried setting the 'Result Column Bindings' property to 'AttractionKey' (my primary key field), but nothing. I have returned the Scope_Identity() in the insert stored procedure.

Like I said, I am at my wits end. I have no clue what I am missing.

Comment: Is the record actually created in the database? Is the PK field in the DB an identity field?

Comment: If you right click on a key field in EDMX designer and select Properties, what's the value of StoreGeneratedPattern property?

Comment: rism - yes, the record gets created. As for the StoredGeneratedpattern property, it is set to Identity. ([Entity Key] = True, [Name]=AttractionKey, [Nullable]=False, [StoredGeneratedPattern]=Identity, [Type]=Int32

Comment: So I believe I solved my problem. I went to my stored procedure mapping for Attraction and added AttractionKey in the Result Column Binding. When I did that, I got the following error: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). So I took a look at my INSERT sproc and modified its results to say: SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) AS [AttractionKey] and now it is working. Not really sure what is going on, but for now I am happy.